# HTML+CSS Formatting a button with <a> and <h>

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, box

I've recently started learning HTML and CSS, and I've got this problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPKL9.png

The 3 buttons with "Spausk mane" should have the text at the bottom of the box, or like 10px off the bottom but centered. Line-height, margins etc. aren't working for some reason. Also the hover settings doesn't work for them, because I think I went wrong somewhere with the 'h3' and 'a' tag formatting, help? :S

HTML:

```
     <div class="cta-wrap cf"> 
          <a href="#" class="cta"><h3>Spausk <br> mane</h3></a>
          <a href="#" class="cta"><h3>Spausk <br> mane</h3></a>
          <a href="#" class="cta"><h3>Spausk <br> mane</h3></a>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
a.cta {
          color:white;
          text-decoration: none;
          text-align: center;
       }
a:hover.cta {}

.cta h3 {
            background-color:#287D7D;
            width: 150px;
            height: 110px;
            float:left;
            margin: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
        }
```

Comment: If you want to move text please use padding. if you use padding reduce width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style single line text buttons this way to make them fat and centered (vertically):

```
height: 110px;
line-height: 110px;
```

If you plan on having wrapped text in the buttons you can use:

```
padding: 3em 0;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that, if I use line-height it just spreads the 2 lines "Spausk" and "mane" away from each other

Comment: Yes. Then use the 2nd option. Read again what I've answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
.cta-wrap a:hover h3,
.cta-wrap a h3:hover{
     color:red;
     background-color:yellow;
 }
```

Comment: Thank You, that fixed the hover, what about the text placement? Line-height and margins aren't doing anything :/

Answer (score 0):

I've modified a little bit your CSS. using `display:table` and `table-cell` you can center the text.

CHECK the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/polefazu/2/edit)** for more info.

```
.cta-wrap{display:table;}

a.cta {
color:white;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
float:left;
margin: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
display:block;
}
a.cta h3 {
background-color:#287D7D;
width: 150px;
height: 110px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}

a.cta h3:hover {background:red;}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there some way to move the text up a little bit now? Because if I use vertical-align:bottom; it sticks to the bottom completely. Also, with your code, for some reason, it inserts spaces into my table below the buttons :o